# how do you programmatically invoke a listview label edit

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

in C# I'd like to invoke the label edit of a newly added item to a ListView.
basically, if I have a *click here to add* scenario, as soon as the new item is added, I want the text label to be in a user editable state.
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[found it!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.beginedit.aspx)

```
ListViewItem::BeginEdit();
```

Comment: I know this question is old, but if you're reading this, can you give an example of how you add the item and then put it in edit mode?  I'm trying what I think should be working (Items.Add("").BeginEdit()), but I do this when they double click in the ListView, not on some button press.  When this happens, the item never goes into edit mode.  Thanks.

Comment: @Chad add `item.Selected = true;` before calling `item.BeginEdit()`.